# Build variable name dynamically and access its content with Ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

I have an ansible playbook, which I need to compare values returned from a task to a variable loaded from metadata file.

This metadata can be in any format, and I decided to go with YAML.

What I'm trying to achieve is to **build a variable name from another variable + extra stuff and then lookup this value.**

I've searched for answers over the web but I couldn't find any. There are also some similar questions here on SO, but they don't address exactly my issue.

Here's the code:

temp_task.yml

```
---
  - name: Temp task
    hosts: xenservers
    gather_facts: no
    vars_files:
      - vars/xenservers_metadata.yml

    tasks:
      - command: ls /home  # just a dummy task..
        ignore_errors: yes

      - set_fact: nic={{ inventory_hostname }}.network
      - debug: msg={{ nic }}
      - debug: msg={{ xen_perf.network }}
```

xenservers_metadata.yml

```
---
  - xen:
      network:
        - xenbr0: "9b8be49c-....-....-...-..."
```

I'm trying to get the two debug messages print the same thing. One was constructed dynamically by `{{ inventory_hostname }}.network` while the other is explicit variable I loaded.

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xen_perf] => {
    "msg": "xen.network"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xen] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "xenbr0": "9b8be49c-....-....-...-..."
        }
    ]
}
```

The first debug just prints the string. The second prints the actual data I need. How can I achieve the second data output by constructing the variable/attribute dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t build the variable name dynamically in your example.

All variables (not facts) are stored in `vars` structure and you can access them this way:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ vars[inventory_hostname].network }}"
```

Comment: this works for network, but if I try to get value based on the key 'xenbr0' the operation fails. Any idea how can I reach `vars[inventory_hostname].network.xenbr0` ?

Comment: Just like you wrote.

Comment: My YAML variable file was wrong, that's why it failed. I had added a `-` before the xenbr0 value. Apparently it shouldn't be there. Thanks